# Regular Expression match and change the format if doesn't match

Tags: python, regex

I need help to match each line of the file with the REGEX format and if doesn't match reformat the line based on the REGEX format.

About the file: The only thing changes in each line is the 10 digits (1234567890) after the qr in every row.

Problem: Right now I am NOT able to do the match. My output is just printing ELSE output even with the correct format.

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
import re

filepath = 'fruit.txt'

def main():
    # mode function to check that the file is in open mode.
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        cnt = 1
        for line in fp:
            #Matching correct format: fruit_id (iid 43210, qr 1234567890,mo 001212121)
            matchLn = re.match(r'fruit_id\s+\(iid\s+43210,\s+qr\s+1\d\{10},mo\s+001212121\)', line, re.M|re.I)
            print("Matching Pattern with : {}".format(line))
            #if pattern.match(line):
            if matchLn:
                print('Matched format:', cnt)
            else:
                print('Check the format of the line:', cnt)
                # I need to make sure the line matches the format)
            cnt = cnt + 1
main()
```

fruit.txt:

```
   fruit_id (iid 43210, qr 1234567890,mo 001212121)
   fruit_id (iid 43210, qr 1235567890,mo 001212121)
   fruit_id (iid 43210, qr 1225367890,mo 001212121)
   fruit_id (iid 43210, qr 1274567890,mo 001212121)
   fruit_id (iid 43210, qr 1279567890,mo 001212121)
   fruit_id (iid 43210, qr 1245637890,mo 001212121)
   fruit_id (iid 43210, qr 1234457890,mo 001212121)
   fruit_id (iid 43210, qr 1234532890,mo 001212121)
```

Output:

```
Matched format: 1
Matched format: 2
Matched format: 3
Matched format: 4
Matched format: 5
Matched format: 6
Matched format: 7
Matched format: 8
Copying the file to a path..
```

Comment: Show a sample of the input, the desired and real output (edit the question).

Comment: if you can solve your problem by writing a simple function why use regex then ?

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. As well, please make a [mre]. See [ask] for more tips.

Comment: Sorry guys I am still a noob. Reformated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex contains following issues:

- The prefix of the dynamic number uses 'dn' instead 'qr'
- An additional '1' is matched preceding the dynamic number
- The quantifier '{' is escaped, therefore matched as literal
- The prefix of the last value uses 'sp' instead 'mo'

Here is an example regex fixing those issues:

```
\s*fruit_id\s+\(iid\s+43210,\s+qr\s+\d{10},mo\s+001212121\)
```

Also see that regex in [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/r/0pwfbM/1).